# How to replace the HeaderCells of a DataGridView with custom headers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

When to replace a `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` with a custom `HeaderCell` (here: `CustomDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`), when the `DataSource` of a DataGridView is already set to a `DataTable` object and also preserve the text of the previous HeaderCell, which is set to the name of the corresponding Column of the DataTable?

I have a custom header class for a `DataGridView`:

```
public class CustomDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
{
    // adds a button to the header
}
```

A `DataTable` is being set as the `DataSource`, the Columns are created automatically. How can I replace the default header cells with custom header cells (instances of the above)?

**More detail**

[image]

The problem to solve is, a `DataGridView` needs to have clickable buttons embedded in its header cells, where the arrow is pointing to in the screenshot above. For that, there is a class `CustomDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`. To show data in the `DataGridView`, a `DataTable` is being assigned as its data source. For example:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

After doing this, the `DataGridView` will have columns corresponding to those in the `DataTable`. I have derived a class from the default header classes, so that the buttons appear inside the column headers.

Comment: Will you elaborate more in detail. exactly what are trying to do.

Comment: @BheemsenSingh I will add more detail to the post.

Comment: @MongZhu I think you misunderstood. In short, when I assign a `DataTable`, I want the column header types to be `CustomDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`, instead of the default `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`, but still with header names corresponding to the `DataTable`.

Comment: Have you tried to loop through the collection of columns and replace them with custom columns?

Comment: there is actually a click event that can be used to tackle this job.

Comment: @MaciejLos yes, but I am unsure how to actually change their type. Is it as simple as creating a new instance of `CustomDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`, settings it's `Value`, adding it to the collection, then removing the old default cell?

Comment: @MaciejLos the problem is the custom header cells cannot be add to the columns like: `dataGridView.Columns.Add(customHeaderCell)`, because it only accepts ojbects of type `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`, which is the default type.

Comment: [Remove Autogenerated Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/remove-autogenerated-columns-from-a-wf-datagridview-control), [DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Add custom column, not custom cell.

Comment: Also you can simply set [HeaderText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext?view=netcore-3.1) property

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov could you add that as an answer? Your suggestion seems likely to work (even if I haven't tested it yet). If it is helpful I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [HeaderCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headercell) of a DataGridViewColumn can be replaced at any time.

Even when the DataSource of the DataGridView is already set: in this case, you may want to set the Style of the current `HeaderCell` to your new cell, in case some values need to be replicated (when the Column are auto-generated, there's probably not much to copy, but since the Style property can be set, let's set it).

In the example, I'm adding a **`ReplaceHeaderCell()`** method to the custom `HeaderCell`, which receives the instance of the current header, copies some properties then disposes of it before replacing the corresponding Column's `HeaderCell` with itself.

If the Button we're adding to the `HeaderCell` is a standard Button Control, this Control must be added to the `DataGridView.Controls` collection (so it will be visible and brought to front).
If the Button is painted, overriding the [Paint method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewheadercell.paint), of course there's nothing to parent :).

**Note:** the Button is added in the **`OnDataGridViewChanged()`** method override. This method is called each time a DataGridView object becomes the owner of the HeaderCell. When the Parent DataGridView changes, the Button is automatically added to its Controls collection.

► Here, the Paint method is overridden anyway: it's used to calculate the HeaderCell Text padding, so the Button won't overlap and hide the Column's text (this procedure needs to be fine-tuned, in relation to the Button's specifics).

To replace the current `HeaderCell` of a Column (e.g., `Column[0]`), just create a new instance of the custom `HeaderCell` and call the `ReplaceHeaderCell()` method, passing the reference of the `HeaderCell` to replace:

```
var newButtonHeaderCell = new DGVButtonHeaderCell();
newButtonHeaderCell.ReplaceHeaderCell(dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell);
```

This is how it works:

[image: DataGridView Custom HeaderCell]

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class DGVButtonHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
{
    public readonly Button button;
    private Padding m_ButtonPadding = Padding.Empty;

    public DGVButtonHeaderCell(int buttonWidth = 40)
    {
        button = new Button() { BackColor = Color.Orange, Width = buttonWidth };
        m_ButtonPadding = new Padding(button.Width + 2, 0, 0, 0);
        button.Click += ButtonClick;
    }

    public void ReplaceHeaderCell(DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell previousHeader)
    {
        if (previousHeader == null) return;
        SetStandardValues(previousHeader);
        var dgv = previousHeader.DataGridView;
        dgv.Columns[previousHeader.OwningColumn.Index].HeaderCell = this;
        previousHeader.Dispose();
    }

    private void SetStandardValues(DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell previous)
    {
        if (previous == null) return;
        Style = previous.Style;
        button.Font = Style.Font ?? previous.DataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font;
        // etc.
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnClick(new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(ColumnIndex, RowIndex));
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked me");
    }

    protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()
    {
        if (DataGridView == null) return;
        DataGridView.Controls.Add(button);
    }

    protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle bounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts parts)
    {
        cellStyle.Padding = Padding.Add(m_ButtonPadding, cellStyle.Padding);
        base.Paint(g, clipBounds, bounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advBorderStyle, parts);
        button.Location = new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top + 2);
        button.Height = bounds.Height - 4;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            button.MouseClick -= ButtonClick;
            button.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```