# DataGridView data not showing on adding button to column header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a custom column header which was created as below

```
public readonly Button button = new Button();
            private Padding m_ButtonPadding = Padding.Empty;

            public DataGridViewButtonHeaderCell(int buttonWidth = 40)
            {
                button = new Button()
                {
                    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                    Width = buttonWidth,
                    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                    Image = Properties.Resources.Add
                };
                button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                m_ButtonPadding = new Padding(button.Width + 2, 0, 0, 0);
                button.Click += ButtonClick;
            }

            public void ReplaceHeaderCell(DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell previousHeader)
            {
                if (previousHeader == null) return;
                SetStandardValues(previousHeader);
                var dgv = previousHeader.DataGridView;
                dgv.Columns[previousHeader.OwningColumn.Index].HeaderCell = this;
                previousHeader.Dispose();
            }

            private void SetStandardValues(DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell previous)
            {
                if (previous == null) return;
                this.Style = previous.Style;
                button.Font = this.Style.Font ?? previous.DataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font;
                // etc.
            }

            private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OnClick(new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(ColumnIndex, RowIndex));
                MessageBox.Show("You clicked me");
            }

            protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()
            {
                base.OnDataGridViewChanged();
                if (this.DataGridView == null) return;
                this.DataGridView.Controls.Add(button);
            }

            protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle bounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts parts)
            {
                cellStyle.Padding = Padding.Add(m_ButtonPadding, cellStyle.Padding);
                base.Paint(g, clipBounds, bounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advBorderStyle, parts);
                button.Location = new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top + 2);
                button.Height = bounds.Height - 4;
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    button.MouseClick -= ButtonClick;
                    button.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
```

The custom column headers are created as below

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in GridV.Columns)
                {
                    var newButtonHeaderCell = new DataGridViewButtonHeaderCell();
                    newButtonHeaderCell.ReplaceHeaderCell(dc.HeaderCell);
                }
```

The datagridview is bound to a datatable via bindingsource.
The problem is that, after adding the custom column headers, my data does not appear in the datagridview unless i click on a column header. Why does this happen?
P.S. found this code from a helpful user here.

Comment: If you get no errors, what happens when your run your code? This will depend on if you manually add the grid columns or if they are “auto” generated from the grid’s data source… but… do the column headers appear as you expect and just no data? Or… Is the grid “empty” without headers? I am guessing you may need to post a small [mre] that reproduces your claim. In my small test, the data appears as expected using a `DataTable` as a data source to a `BindingSource` and then setting the grids data source to the binding source.

Comment: Well, I wrote that code, posted here: [How to replace the HeaderCells of a DataGridView with custom headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63011702/7444103). As you can see in the animation, the data is is visible and a BindingSource is actually used there. There's something in the code you didn't post.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies! @Jimi thanks for the code!
I found where issue occurs, but not why. It has to do with the way the form was called. if it is called in like so, data loads:
            Testform frm = new Testform();
            frm.Show();
But if this:
                 tstfrm = new Test_form();
                tstfrm.MdiParent = this;
                tstfrm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                tstfrm.Location = LocateOnScreen(tstfrm); //to center on screen
                tstfrm.FormClosed += (o, ea) => tstfrm = null;
                tstfrm.Show();