# How to add button to a specific DataGridView C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview

[image]

Hi, I am very new to C# and WinForms. Just like this image showing, I added `DataGridView_B`  to `DataGridView_A`, where `DataGridView_B` is usually invisible and only be visible when certain function is called. As far to this step, everything works well.
Then I decided to add a button `Button_Close` to `DataGridView_B`, so when I don't need `DataGridView_B`, I can click the button and it would be invisible again.

Code that I used to bound B to A, which works fine:

```
this.DataGridView_A.Controls.Add(this.DateGridView_B);
...
this.DateGridView_B.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
```

Code that I used to bound button to B, which has issue:

```
this.DataGridView_B.Controls.Add(this.Button_Close);
```

As long as I bound button to B, the button disappears, then I tried to comment out this line of code, the button is still gone.

Does anyone have any thoughts about why the code acts like this?

Note: the button is added manually by the `Toolbox`, not programmatically.

Comment: Surely life would be simpler to just draw two DataGridView and a button on a form and show/hide one of them as appropriate

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah I understand that, but B datagridview won't be needed all the time, and A has more content to display which would need a whole page including the space that B is taking up currently.

Comment: [DataGridView with Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549704/3110834)

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Just expand A vertically when B is not shown

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you, but I think this post is about adding a button within a row, and I would like to add a button to the right upper corner, not within any rows.

Comment: @EmoryLu Do you mean on the row header of the last column? Well, why not just putting a real button control over the DataGridView (in designer or code)?

Comment: Header with Buttons: [How to replace the HeaderCells of a DataGridView with custom headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63011702/7444103) -- Custom design of the Header: [Problem while scrolling merged Header Cells of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67246419/7444103)

Comment: @EmoryLuHave you tried any of these helpful answers?  If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

When you drop items in from the `Toolbox` instead of programmatically adding them, their location is absolute to the top left corner of the form.

In your example, I'll make the following assumptions:

`DataGridView_A` is 400 x 800 px.
`DataGridView_B` is 400 x 300 px.
`Button_Close`  is at `Point` (350, 510). (Relative to top left corner of form)

When you programmatically add `Button_Close` to `DataGridView_B`, the location of the button is persevered but in the wrong way. It keeps the `Point` (350, 510) and not the `Point` relative to `DataGridView_B`. This puts `Button_Close` at `Point` (350, 510) relative to `DataGridView_B` when you add it, thus it is not in view.

This can be fixed by adding the button and moving its location to your desired location. Example:

```
//Add DataGridView_B to DataGridView_A
this.DataGridView_A.Controls.Add(this.DataGridView_B);
this.DataGridView_B.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;

//Add Button_Close to DataGridView_B
this.DataGridView_B.Controls.Add(this.Button_Close);
//10 px margin on top and right
this.Button_Close.Location = new Point(this.DataGridView_B.Width - (this.Button_Close.Width + 10), 10);
```