# How do I make DataGridView header text align with cell text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The very standart WinForms `DataGridView` with some data (both columns are `string`) looks like this. Notice the header and data don't align, header has some empty space on the left (marked yellow on the first column).

[image: example DataGridView with highlighted space in the header I want to get rid of]

How do I make it go away?

There are similar questions out there, but they are about header text being off-center, in this case it's left aligned.

What I tried:

```cs
grd.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

column.HeaderCell.Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
column.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;
```

I know there is the `CellPainting`-Event I can probably use, but I'd really rather not.

Comment: You could set the RowTemplate's `DefaultCellStyle.Padding.Left` to (IIRC) 5~6 pixels, but this also affects the CheckBox Columns, so you probably have to reset the DefaultCellStyle all TextBox Columns

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this will be my plan B. (Ideally I would move the header text to the left, not everything else to the right)

Comment: Then you have to do it the *hard way*. Take the custom Column Header from here: [How to replace the HeaderCells of a DataGridView with custom headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63011702/7444103). See the `Paint()` method override: if you change the `bounds` as, e.g., `var newBounds = bounds; newBounds.Offset(new Point(-5, 0));` and pass the `newBounds` to `base.Paint()` instead of `bounds`, you move the text 5 pixels to the left (of course you also have to increase the width by 5 pixels) -- Note that the default offset of the Headers' text is related to the rendering with visual styles

Comment: I'm just *really* hoping to avoid doing this. I mean, how hard can it be to just disable some text padding? (I suspect the answer is "very" :'( )

Comment: The Header's text `Padding.Left` is `0`, the text is rendered inside the aforementioned bounds (for specific reasons). If you want to override this behavior, you have to override the procedure that paints the text. Nothing really complicated. Even less when it's already been written

Comment: Yes, it's not that complicated, but it's still much more cumbersome than just setting/overriding something to be 0, f.e. Also, it doesn't quite work: it looks like the header of the column to the right draws its background on top of the column separator. Handling CellPainting and using TextRenderer.DrawText works better (on the first glance, but probably has other pitfalls).