# Is DataRepeater available also in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

I'm doing a remake in C# of an application written in VisualBasic.
This app contains 3 or 4 DataRepeater that, for certain reasons, is not plenty supported by Microsoft (infact the VisualBasicPowerPack is from third part).
Is DataRepeater available also in C#? If not is there a solution to avoid it?
Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Can't you use a DataGridView instead?

Comment: @Jimi, i'm very interested in a different solution. Why do you suggest DataGridView instead? I don't know DataGridView...it's possible to "create" a visualization similar at the DataReader? I noticed that with DataGridView all is displayed in rows and columns...is not possible to use a "free" layout like DataReader?

Comment: DataReader => DataRepeater? -- Not really, without heavy customization. You could also build an UserControl, bind its properties and use a FlowLayoutPanel / TableLayoutPanel to host instances of the UserControl. Anyway, I have no idea what layout you're after. Maybe post an image of the current layout

Comment: @Jimi, sorry...yes, i intend DataRepeater
I posted an image of my actual DataRepeater page.

Comment: That's a quite simple design. You could use either  DataGridView (suggested), or a TableLayoutPanel, adding Controls to each row (more manual work, though). To customize the appearence of the DGV's Headers, see, e.g., [How to replace the HeaderCells of a DataGridView with custom headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63011702/7444103) (custom Header Cells) or [Problem while scrolling merged Header Cells of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67246419/7444103) (custom Painting) -- A DataGridView has a VirtualMode, as the DataRepeater. It's highly customizable (to the Cell level)

Comment: @Jimi, thanks for your answer. I'll try also this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can download [Visual Basics Power Pack Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc488277(v=vs.120)) and use them in C#. After you install the pack you should be able to see `DataRepeater` in your toolbox window.

Comment: I've downloaded the pack you suggested and installed it. But, when i try to use a simple control like the rectangle shape, an error is displayed....."Impossible to create the component RectangleShape" System.IO.FileNotFoundException: It wasn't possible to load the file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.9.0 etc. etc." I use the Visual Studio Community Version 17.7.6

Comment: @Livio System.Windows.Shapes belongs to WPF but your question is labelled as winforms. Are you referencing PresentationFramework library?

Comment: @derloopkat no, i don't

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I downloaded the most recent PowerPack. Thanks to all for the suggestions.